# How does Maven understand release:prepare command?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin which would download and install jars from Maven central as system tools. So I want my line to be like

`mvn install-plugin:install org.chaschev:cap4j:1.0`

similar to Ruby's

`gem install capistrano`

This plugin would gather all the needed information about the shortcuts to create from the JAR. I.e. this jar would contain a class implementing an installation interface.

How does Maven understand that in order to execute a command like `release:prepare` it requires to download the release plugin and to run it? Any better/other way to do this?

Comment: Just a question: Do you really like to create a plugin which installs artifacts into Maven central? You know that it already exists? Apart from that via install you wan't deploy artifacts to maven central they must be deployed.

Comment: Oops, sorry for misconception, I'll update the post. I want to create a plugin to download a jar from Maven Central and install this jar locally as a system tool. Like it's done in ruby with `gem install xxx`

Comment: Downloading an artifact from maven central simply as a dependency within a project or via dependency plugin. If you like to download only files you can use the [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/). Furthermore what do you mean by a system tool?

Comment: By a system tool I mean for example a shortcut to my JAR created under a PATH (i.e. $JAVA_HOME/bin) and available from the command line. That's how it's done in capistrano.

I'm currently googling on how to download and run a Mojo from my plugin deployed to Maven Central, this would be enough for the job.

Comment: You can use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute a class/programm etc. via Maven. Hm...may be i misunderstand a thing. Have you created a plugin and want to use that plugin or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a bit confusing, I know. I want to provide my user a way to install his jars to his users' desktops. By: 1. Placing his JAR to Maven Central 2. Placing my plugin to Maven Central 3. Invoking magical `mvn run-my-installation-mojo! with params user-artifact` 4. It will download the user's artifact and create a shortcut to one of it's classes in `$JAVA_HOME/bin/user-tool` 5. User will run this tool with user-tool. Win! So this would be similar to `apt-get install` command, but for Maven artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good to use default Maven groups for your own project.
Instead, define your own group for your plugin, like this:

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.chaschev</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

And rename your plugin from `cap4j` to `cap4j-maven-plugin`. Then Maven will discover your plugin without further cahnges in POM.

Alternative, without `<pluginGroups>`, just put following to your POM:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.chaschev</groupId>
    <artifactId>cap4j</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. I've just googled it here in a [Jetty plugin](https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how the relation between plugin/goal in the comamnd line and plugin implementation is defined? Then the answer is `plugin.xml`. See plugin.xml for release plugin, e.g. maven-release-plugin-2.0.jar:

```
<goalPrefix>release</goalPrefix>
...
  <mojos>
    <mojo>
      <goal>help</goal>
      ...
    <mojo>
      <goal>prepare</goal>
      ...
```

Or do you mean, how Maven discovers which plugins are available? Then the answer is:

- There are two default groups where plugins are searched, `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`
- For your own plugin you may want to use name `${prefix}-maven-plugin`, e.g. `cap4j-maven-plugin`
- You can keep your name `cap4j`, but then put the plugin description to your POM, under `<plugins>`
- If you want your build to work at other machines, they should point `<pluginRepositories>` in POM or in settings.xml to your plugin repository

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that my plugin must be placed in one of two groups to be available as a command, i.e. be an Apache project or can it be my personal project?